# How does Visual Studio syntax-highlight strings in the Regex constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Hi fellow programmers and nerds!

When creating regular expressions Visual Studio, the IDE will highlight the string if it's preceded by a verbatim identifier (for example, `@"Some string`). This looks something like this:

[image: A screenshot of the highlighting]

(Notice the way the string is highlighted). Most of you will have seen this by now, I'm sure.

My problem: I am using a package acquired from NuGet which deals with regular expressions, and they have a function which takes in a regular expression string, however their function doesn't have the syntax highlighting.

[image: the function without highlighting]

As you can see, this just makes reading the Regex string just a pain. I mean, it's not all-too-important, but it would make a difference if we can just have that visually-helpful highlighting to reduce the time and effort one's brain uses trying to decipher the expression, especially in a case like mine where there will be quite a quantity of these expressions.

**The question**

So what I'm wanting to know is, is there a way to make a function highlight the string this way*, or is it just something that's hardwired into the IDE for the specific case of the Regex c-tor? Is there some sort of annotation which can be tacked onto the function to achieve this with minimal effort, or would it be necessary to use some sort of extension?

*I have wrapped the call to `AddStyle()` into one of my own functions anyway, and the string will be passed as a parameter, so if any modifications need to be made to achieve the syntax-highlight, they can be made to my function. Therefore the fact that the `AddStyle()` function is from an external library should be irrelevant.

If it's a lot of work then it's not worth my time, somebody else is welcome to develop an extension to solve this, but if there is a way...

**Important distinction**

Please bear in mind I am talking about Visual Studio, *NOT* Visual Studio Code.

Also, if there is a way to pull the original expression string from the Regex, I might do it that way, since performance isn't a huge concern here as this is a once-on-startup thing, however I would *prefer* not to do it that way. I don't actually need the Regex object.

Comment: It seems that you can mark the string with a special comment to get syntax highlighting: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-studio-2019-net-productivity/#regex-language-support

Comment: Aha, that's great, thank you, good find! This works by putting the comment above the string when passing it into the function, but not when placed above the function taking the string in as a parameter. For my purposes, this will be fine.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, I would like to accept it as the solution. I had also overlooked the fact that this seems to be a Visual studio Preview feature and may get further development in the future. Hopefully they can make it support functions with string inputs, or allow the comment to be used once for a specified number of lines, rather than the comment being placed above each line, however I can put up with it, as I need to comment what each expression is anyway, and you can write anything after the 'language=regex' part.

Comment: Done, see below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> .NET 7 introduces the new `[StringSyntax(...)]` attribute, which is used in .NET 7 on more than 350 `string`, `string[]`, and `ReadOnlySpan<char>` parameters, properties, and fields to highlight to an interested tool what kind of syntax is expected to be passed or set.
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/?WT_mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&hmsr=joyk.com&utm_source=joyk.com&utm_medium=referral

So for a method argument you should just use:

```cs
void MyMethod([StringSyntax(StringSyntaxAttribute.Regex)] string regex);
```

Here is a video demonstrating the feature: https://youtu.be/Y2YOaqSAJAQ

Comment: This is a much better solution if you are able to upgrade to .NET 7. The comment syntax requires you to add the `/* language=regex */` comment to every method call, where as this solution you only have to specify it in the method definition.

Answer (score 39):

According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-studio-2019-net-productivity/#regex-language-support and https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-regex-editing.htm you can mark the string with a special comment to get syntax highlighting:

```
  // language=regex
  var str = @"[A-Z]\d+;
```

or

```
  MyMethod(/* language=regex */ @"[A-Z]\d+);
```

(the comment may contain more than just this `language=regex` part)

The first linked blog talks about a preview, but this feature is also present in the final product.

Comment: is there a way to tell the ide a method argument is a regex pattern?

Comment: When calling the method: yes (just add a comment as described). I'm not aware of any attribute that can be used in the declaration.